# Show that $n$ lines separate the plane into $\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$ regions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

> Show that $n$ lines separate the plane into  $\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$ regions if no two of these lines are parallel and no three pass through a common point.

I know we start with the base case, where, if we call the above equation P(n), P(0), for 0 lines would be 0.  But I really have no idea how to begin the inductive step.  How do we know what k+1 we're supposed to arrive at?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like $\binom{n-1}{2} + 1$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339750/greatest-number-of-planes-we-can-get-when-dividing-with-lines-and-circles

Answer (score 23):

Here is the way I usually think about this (it sort of uses induction).

With $0$ lines, there is $1$ region and no intersections of lines.

Each time a line is added and it crosses $k$ other lines it adds $k+1$ regions and $k$ intersections. Another way of looking at this is that for each line and $k$ intersections added, $k+1$ regions are added (the number of added lines and intersections).

Therefore, the number of regions is $1+\text{the number of lines}+\text{the number of intersections}$. With $n$ lines, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ intersections (if no two lines are parallel and no three lines are coincident).

Thus, the number of regions is $\binom{n}{2}+n+1=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n+1=\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$.

Comment: @Bob: Note that robjohn’s answer essentially gives you your induction step: when you add the $(n+1)$-st line, it cuts $n+1$ regions in two, so it adds $n+1$ regions. Add that to the $\frac12(n^2+n+2)$ given you by your induction hypothesis, and you get $\frac12(n^2+3n+4)=\frac12\left((n+1)^2+(n+1)+2\right)$.

Comment: After this long time hello @robjohn , I'm wondering why the two lines that we add should intersect each other couldn't we chose two lines that are parallel we would have $k+2$ regions no? (Edit: nevermind I just saw the remark on the answer below)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we draw $n$ straight lines on the plane so that every pair of
lines intersects (but no $3$ lines intersect at a common point). Into 
how many regions do these $n$ lines divide the plane?

With $n = 1$ we divide the plane into $2$ regions. With $n = 2$ we have $4$ regions; with $n = 3$ we get $7$ regions. A fourth line will meet the 
other $3$ lines in $3$ points and so traverse $4$ regions, dividing them 
into $2$ parts and adding $4$ new regions. In general the $n^{th}$ line will 
add $n$ new regions:

$$u(1) = 2$$
$$u(2) = 4$$
$$u(3) = 7$$
$$u(4) = 11$$

And so on, where $u(n) =$ number of regions with $n$ lines.

We get the recurrence relationship:

$$u(n+1) = u(n) + (n+1)$$

We get the following chain of equations:

$$u(n) - u(n-1) = n$$
$$u(n-1) - u(n-2) = n-1$$
$$u(n-2) - u(n-3) = n-2$$
$$\vdots$$
$$u(4) - u(3)   =  4$$
$$u(3) - u(2)   =  3$$
$$u(2) - u(1)   =  2$$

Adding these equations, we get:
$$u(n) - u(1)   =  2 + 3 + 4 + ..... + (n-1) + n$$

All other terms on the left cancel between rows, and we are left with:

$$u(n) = u(1) + 2 + 3 + 4 + \ldots + n$$

We know, $u(1) = 2$

Thus:

$$u(n) = 1 + (1+2+3+4+ \ldots+n)$$
$$\implies u(n) = 1 + \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$\implies u(n) = \dfrac{n^2 + n + 2}{2}$$

So:

$$u(n) = \dfrac{n^2 + n + 2}{2}$$

**Remark** $\,$ If you allow parallel lines and more than $2$ lines to intersect at a 
point, the above relation doesn't hold.

The answer then depends on the number of lines intersecting at a point or the number of lines which are parallel to one another.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to arrive at this formula. I will first give the explanation for the proof of the formula by induction followed by a derivation of the same formula by combinatorial methods.

**Proof by Induction:**

Let $f(n)$ be the maximum number of regions into which $n$ lines divide a plane.

Now, let us add the $(n+1)$th line. Provided none of the lines are collinear and no 3 lines intersect at the same point upon adding the new line, this new $(n+1)$th line would make an intersection with each of the previous $n$ lines. Hence the new line passes thorugh $(n+1)$ regions dividing each of these regions into two. Hence $(n+1)$ new regions are created when the $(n+1)$th line is added. This means that:

$f(n+1)=f(n)+(n+1)$.

Let me demonstrate this with an example:

Assume that we have 2 lines dividing a plane into 4 regions. When we add a 3rd line, it will intersect the previous 2 lines and will be passing through 3 regions: the region on one side of the 1st line, the region between the 1st line and 2nd line, and the region on the other side of the 2nd line. Hence 3 new regions have been created.

So, now we have the conditions: $f(n)=f(n-1)+n$ and $f(0)=1$

$f(n)=f(n-1)+n$

$f(n-1)=f(n-2)+n-1$

$f(n-2)=f(n-3)+n-2$

.....

$f(2)=f(1)+2$

$f(1)=f(0)+1$

$f(0)=1$

Adding the above equations gives:

$f(n)=1+(1+2+3+...+n)$

So,
$f(n)=1+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2 + n + 2}{2}$

This can also be expressed as:

$f(n)=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{0}$

**Combinatorial Proof:**

Each region in the plane (except for the regions which are not bounded below) has exacly one *"deepest point"* (i.e. a point at the deepest *"corner"* in that region). This *deepest point* is the *deepest point* of only that particular region and not of any of the other 3 regions adjacent to it. We can also notice that an intersection between any two lines will create exactly one *deepest point* belonging to one particular region. The maximum number of points of intersections created by $n$ lines is $\binom{n}{2}$. Hence, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ *deepest points*.

Now let us consider the regions which do not have a *deepest point*. These are the regions which are not bounded below. So we cannot pick out a *deepest point* for these regions. There are exactly $n+1$ such regions.

So the total number of regions is $\binom{n}{2}+n+1 = \binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{0}$.

There is also a 3 dimensional version of this problem which asks for the maximum number of regions into which n planes divide a space. The answer turns out to be $\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{0}$. This can also be proved by the induction method (considering the number of regions divided by the $(n+1)$th plane) as well as the combinatorial method (using the concept of *deepest points*).