# How many regions do $n$ lines divide the plane into?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose you draw $n \ge 0$ distinct lines in the plane, one after another, none of the lines parallel to any other and no three lines intersecting at a common point. The plane will, as a result, be divided into how many different regions $L_n$? Find an expression for $L_n$ in terms of $L_{n-1}$, solve it explicitly, and indicate what is $L_{10}$.

I have tried to come up with a solution but cannot. A little guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: *Please give your questions more descriptive titles*. People who are searching the site need to be able to see what a question is about from its title.

Comment: I feel like a similar question has been asked before but don't know where I might find the question. Does anyone know if this is a duplicate?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339750/greatest-number-of-planes-we-can-get-when-dividing-with-lines-and-circles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each new line intersects other $n$ lines in one point and divides each previous region of space into two regions. Therefore each new line adds new  $n+1$ region and so we have:
$$
L_{n+1}=L_n+n+1
$$
with $L_1=2$.

Indeed you can see that $L_n=1+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and hence $L_{10}=56$.

Comment: The formula is correct but a new line does not divide each previous region.

Answer (score 9):

HINT: If you already have $n$ lines and add an $(n+1)$-st line, the new line crosses each of the original $n$ lines. Those intersections divide the new line into $k+1$ segments (including the two unbounded segments). Show that each of those segments divides one old region into two new ones. This gives you a recurrence expressing $L_{n+1}$ in terms of $L_n$, and it’s an easy recurrence to solve for a closed form.

Comment: To show that each of those segments divides one old region into two new ones- would proof by induction be sufficient? If not what other ways can be used?

Comment: @diplodocus: It’s simpler than that: you merely have to observe that if you draw a straight line through a bounded region, you divide the region into two regions, one on each side of the line, and that the same thing happens when you draw a straight line through an unbounded region. A *rigorous* proof of this fact requires some pretty heavy-duty topology, but in an elementary course in combinatorics you can take it as pretty much self-evident.